# Can I make this dual function more concise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function;

```
const queuedAction1 = (newlyLoggedInUser) => this.callToFunction(item, newlyLoggedInUser);
const queuedAction2 = (newlyLoggedInUser) => this.callToOtherFunction(item, newlyLoggedInUser);

if (!someCriteria) {
    dispatch(queueAction(queuedAction1));
    dispatch(queueAction(queuedAction2));
    this.showLoginModal();
    return;
}

queuedAction1();
queuedAction2();
```

It doesn't matter which order the `queuedAction` functions fire, so is there I way I can make this whole things more concise? Perhaps using only one `const`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a refactor which should be handled by [codereview.se]

Answer (score 3):

Why not push this into an array?

```
const actions = [
  (newlyLoggedInUser) => this.callToFunction(item, newlyLoggedInUser),
  (newlyLoggedInUser) => this.callToOtherFunction(item, newlyLoggedInUser)
];

if (!someCriteria) {
    actions.forEach(action => queueAction(action));
    this.showLoginModal();
    return;
}

actions.forEach(action => queueAction(action));
```

Whenever you have variables with names `x1`, `x2`, etc. that's usually a sign you need a proper data structure and not just a pile of unrelated variables.

Always try and structure your code in terms of data flow by grouping together related things in a container that makes using them easy.